# Scrolling with the mouse scroll to the height of the blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How to do when scrolling page scrolling occurred exactly at the height of the blocks that are in it (the code inside)?

I do not want to use the library, because, likely, it is necessary to add 2-5 lines of code to solve the problem with scrolling pages when scrolling at the height of the block (a predetermined number of pixels).

The second question is how to make this a smooth scrolling, that was not the feeling that just switched from one unit to another.

```js
function slide() {
  h = document.documentElement.clientHeight
  $(".one, .two, .three").css('height', h);
};

$(window).resize(slide);
$(document).ready(slide);
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.two {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.one {
  background: #CD5;
}
.two {
  background: aquamarine;
}
.three {
  background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Comment: So you want to fire a function when you can see all three `div`s at once?

Comment: I wish for each mouse scroll, the page scrolls to the specified number of pixels, which is equal to the height of the blocks

Comment: So every time you scroll, the page moves down a certain amount rather than the amount that you scrolled by?

Comment: yes (from one block to another)

Comment: OK. I can now work on an answer :D

Comment: This is almost doing it: https://jsfiddle.net/j64nwf2j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind your scroll handler to both mousewheel and DOMMouseScroll event and use (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) to determine the direction of the scroll. Then use $().offset().top to find the top of the div to scroll and $.animate() to do the scrolling.

```js
function slide() {
  h = document.documentElement.clientHeight
  $(".one, .two, .three").css('height', h);
};
$(window).resize(slide);
$(document).ready(slide);


$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  scroll(event);
});

var num = 1;
var scrolling = false;

function scroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      num--;
      num = num < 1 ? 1 : num;
    } else {
      num++;
      num = num > 3 ? 3 : num;
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".num" + num).offset().top
    }, 500, "linear", function() {
      scrolling = false;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.two {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.one {
  background: #CD5;
}
.two {
  background: aquamarine;
}
.three {
  background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one num1"></div>
<div class="two num2"></div>
<div class="three num3"></div>
```

Comment: just a suggestion use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`  

.bind() and .delegate() are deprecated as of jQuery 1.12 and 2.2. These functions work well with no warning message in 1.12 or 2.2, but will not work in next version and (of course) in 3.0. It is strongly recommended to use .on() instead of .bind() and .delegate()

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding I have created a solution on jsfiddle please check https://jsfiddle.net/v7ok83oa/

I am using mousewheel event.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
  <h1>ONE</h1></div>
<div class="two">
  <h1>Two</h1></div>
<div class="three">
  <h1>Three</h1></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.one {
  background: #CD5;
}

.two {
  background: aquamarine;
}

.three {
  background: #2196F3;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      var h = $(document).height();
      var body = $("body");

      $(".one, .two, .three").css('height', h);


      $(document).on('mousewheel', function(e) {

        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 < 0) { // if Mouse wheel up
          var st = $(document).scrollTop();

          body.animate({
            scrollTop: st + h
          }, '500');


        } else if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) { // if Mouse wheel down
          var st = $(document).scrollTop();

          body.animate({
            scrollTop: st - h
          }, '500');
        }
        console.log($('.one').height());

      });

    });
```

**UPDATE**
check this https://jsfiddle.net/v7ok83oa/3/

if you scroll very fast the event triggers before the animation ends I have fixed it

Comment: with large scrolling does not work.
Try to scrolling  fast.

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов check now and let me know